# Godot: Invalid set index error

Tags: gui, godot

I'm trying to make UI for my game and making a button that changes its own focus neighbour when pressed:

`$SettingsButton.focus_neighbour_left = $ItemGrid/Slot2`

But when I press the button, it gives this error:

`Invalid set index 'focus_neighbour_left' (on base: 'TextureButton') with value of type 'TextureButton'.`

I tried searching around but I don't know what this error is telling me or how to fix it.

To be clear, the scene tree isn't changing and Slot2 is a TextureButton.

Answer (score 1):

Thearot figured it out, I just needed to change

`$ItemGrid/Slot2`

to

`$ItemGrid/Slot2.get_path()`

Comment: By the way Godot has [NodePath](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_nodepath.html) literals. For example `@"ItemGrid/Slot2"`. However, written like that it would be relative, which is not good for passing around. Because of that, I would go with `$ItemGrid/Slot2.get_path()` which gives you an absolute one.

Comment: I realised the solution I found is actually incorrect and I didn't do proper testing before posting my answer, but your answer works perfectly! Thanks @Theraot!

Comment: Reminder: you can accept your own answer.